# Remove the 'init' tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

So I found this `init` tag, and it does not have a tag wiki, and only one follower. It seems to be a synonym of `init-file`. Should we merge them, or is there some other use for this tag at the moment?

Comment: @Gilles could be, but nothing said in that question/answer seems to be implemented atm

Comment: @Asad-ullahKhan it was implemented. We manually removed instances of the tag. Now that we have mods we can actually create the synonym. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @Malabarba haha no problem

Comment: @Malabarba When feature request is implemented or bug is fixed, question should get [status-completed]. Please add it to the linked question.